# Maven Local Dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I have a jar included under src/libs. This is necessary because when I run my application on the intended server it will not be able to download external dependencies. I am receiving the following error when building from the command line: NoClassDefFoundError. The dependency in my pom:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>jFuzzyLogic_core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jFuzzyLogic_core</artifactId>
     <scope>system</scope>
     <version>2.0.7</version>
     <systemPath>${basedir}\src\libs\jFuzzyLogic_core.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>
```

I have read conflicting posts on whether or not this is correct and I can not figure out what to do.

The command line as requested:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sourceforge/jFuzz
yLogic/FIS
        at noobbot.Main.<init>(Main.java:41)
        at noobbot.Main.main(Main.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jFuzzyLogic.FIS
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 2 more
```

Also relevant,

```
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for jFuzzyLogic_core:jFuzzyLogic_
core:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}\src\
libs\jFuzzyLogic_core.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 24,
column 22
```

can anyone else suggest how to do this if this is in fact not the correct way?

Comment: Please give the full error console

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try specifying your lib directory as a repository in your `pom.xml` :

```
<repository>
    <id>project_lib</id>
    <name>Repository in project's lib dir</name>
    <layout>default</layout>
    <url>file:///${project.basedir}/lib</url>
</repository>
```

Then in dependency I don't think you'll need to add `<systemPath>` for that Jar.

Comment: Thanks! This may be what I need to do, do I need to replace systemPath with something? I get an error if I remove it.

Comment: What error do you get ? Ideally you should be able to specify the dependency like any other artifact.

Comment: Changed scope to runtime, was able to build successfully but am getting original error when compiling.

Comment: Isn't this working : `<dependency>
     <groupId>jFuzzyLogic_core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jFuzzyLogic_core</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.7</version>`
  </dependency>

Comment: `runtime` scope might throw error during compilation. Better do not add any scope, or change it to `compile`. http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

Comment: adding the <url> tag returns an error: Malformed POM /home/pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'url' (position: START_TAG seen ...</version>\n\n\t    <url>... @17:11)  @ /home/pom.xml, line 17, column 11 -> [Help 2]

Answer (score 5):

In such cases, I normally import the JAR file into the local repository. You can use this command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=name-of-your-jar.jar -DgroupId=your-group-id -DartifactId=your-artifact-id -Dversion=your-version -Dpackaging=jar
```

So, if we take the snippet you put, the command will be:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=commons-validator-1.4.0.jar -DgroupId=jFuzzyLogic_core -DartifactId=jFuzzyLogic_core -Dversion=2.0.7 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Once done, you can setup the dependance without any system path.

Comment: I was able to successfully build it using "mvn install:install-file -Dfile=src\libs\jFuzzyLogic_core.jar -DgroupId=jFuzzyLogic_core -DartifactId=jFuzzyLogic_core -Dversion=2.0.7 -Dpackaging=jar" but get the same error when compiling the built jar.

Comment: Did you remove the <scope> and <systemPath> tags?

Comment: Is there a way to do this without executing the mvn install:instaö command local repository?